# Perl : $_ and $array[$_] issue

Tags: perl

Below is my code , please review.

```
use strict;
my @people = qw{a b c d e f};
foreach (@people){
    print $_,"$people[$_]\n";
}
```

Below is the output,

```
[~/perl]$ perl test.pl
aa             #why the output of $people[$_] is not same with $_?
ba
ca
da
ea
fa
```

Thanks for your asking.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!

Comment: @ikegami, Why not just `use warnings;`?  It's shorter to type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_` is the actual element you're looking at. `$people[$_]` is getting the `$_`th element out of `@people`. It's intended to be used with numerical indices, so it numifies its argument. Taking a letter and "converting" it to a number just converts to zero since it can't parse a number out of it. So `$people[$_]` is just `$people[0]` when `$_` is not a number. If you try the same experiment where some of the list elements are actually numerical, you'll get some more interesting results.

Try:

```
use strict;
my @people = qw{a b c 3 2 1};
foreach (@people){
    print $_,"$people[$_]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
aa
ba
ca
33
2c
1b
```

Since, in the first three cases, we couldn't parse `a`, `b`, or `c` as numbers so we got the zeroth element. Then, we can actually convert `3`, `2`, and `1` to numbers, so we get elements 3, 2, and then 1.

**EDIT:** As mentioned in a comment by @ikegami, put `use warnings` at the top of your file in addition to `use strict` to get warned about this sort of thing.